# How to access the version from the manifest appcache file through javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-appcache, cache-manifest

I'm building a web app with javascript, jquery, html5, php, & mysql.  I'm using an appcache manifest file to cache the web page on the client machines.

Since I'm keeping a version number in the appcache file already (to force the client files to update), I'd like to use this as the version number for the app.  Is there any way to capture the version number from the manifest file through javascript so that I can display it from my web page?

My current appcache file looks like:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# 2013-10-23 v1

CACHE:
/css/bootstrap.css
/js/bootstrap.js
/js/jquery.js
/
/index.html
/img/Logo_16x16_v2.png
/img/glyphicons-halflings.png

NETWORK:
*.php

#FALLBACK:
#/html/ /offline.html
```